# rqt_plot fixed y-axis limits

Tags: rqt-plot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to fix the y-axis of rqt_plot to certain values but as soon as higher values appear, the y-axis rescales. I've found numerous threads autoscaling in rqt_plot but none provide me with a usable solution. I've tried:

- pausing and setting the limits manually, but it simply resets after
- turning off autoscroll and then setting the limits manually
- all 3 possible backends
- Set use only visible data in the widget but even then when higher values appear, the y-axis limits are expanded and not retracted when these high values are out of the view.

I'm running rqt_plot version 0.3.10. Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209492/rqt_plot-fixed-y-axis-limits/) by [niall](https://answers.ros.org/users/22476/niall/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2015-05-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry; this feature isn't implemented.

You can open a feature request ( https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/issues ) or attempt to implement it yourself (add an additional settings item which calls [`set_autoscale()`](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/blob/548ec6886aaaed3295ba9781d8f44aeda73a9f4c/rqt_plot/src/rqt_plot/data_plot/__init__.py#L380) )

Note that *autoscale* and *autoscroll* are two different things - autoscrolling repositions the X axis, and autoscale adjusts the Y axis bounds.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [niall](https://answers.ros.org/users/22476/niall/) on 2015-05-21**:
OK then that's why I couldn't find the feature. I'll see if I can open a feature request. Thanks for your quick response!

**Comment by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on 2018-09-05**:
it looks like there is an open pull request on this matter:
https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_plot/pull/9